# Calculate spearman’s rank correlation for uneven list

Tags: missing-data, ranking, spearman-rho

Consider two lists:

1. Mined List

   - Subject, Score
   - Subject_A , 11
   - Subject_B, 9
   - Subject_C, 9
2. Ground Truth List

   - Subject, Score
   - Subject_A , 17
   - Subject_D, 15

Then, how to compute the difference in ranks for Spearman’s rank correlation coefficient?

```
Subject    | Mined   |  Ground Truth
Subject_A  |   1        |             2
Subject_B  |   2.5      |             ?
Subject_C  |   2.5      |             ?
Subject_D  |   ?        |             1
```

What should be in the place of "?"

Comment: You can compute the correlation only for subjects for which you have scores on both variables. That doesn't rule out trying to estimate the missing scores, but how you might do that in your situation is unclear.